# How to investigate time required to obtain lock - and why - within a procedure

Tags: postgresql, locks

I am stumped on an issue I am having. The true context is rather complicated, but I can boil it down to these functional points (everything else is not related to the problematic table):

- I have a trigger function that contains several `SELECT`s and then an `UPDATE`
- The update takes an unreasonable amount of time to execute ("unreasonable" = > 1.4s)
- The same exact queries when run outside the trigger (for the same rows, parameters, etc.) do not have any issues (i.e. they execute in under 1-2ms)
- I am pretty sure that indexes, etc., are working as necessary; i.e. there shouldn't be any issues.
- There are no circular triggers

  - There is on trigger on the destination table, but even with that removed the behavior is the same.
- I have done *many* tests to no avail, but these are pretty meaningful:

  - when the update is replaced with a `SELECT`, the response time is fast, as expected
  - when the update is replaced with a `SELECT... FOR UPDATE`, the response time is slow, the same as the update
  - ^ this (as well as other things) has led me to possibly believe that the delay is spent waiting to achieve a lock

No other transactions are really happening on that table. I am truly bewildered.

Server context: This is being run in AWS/RDS on db.m5.xlarge.

**What I am looking for** is whether there is a way to get some information about locks that are happening mid-transaction or possibly even a history of acquired locks? Or anything else that can give me insight into what is causing the delay that seems so closely related to acquiring a lock on that table.

Unfortunately, just to make everything even more frustrating, I cannot replicate the issue when I attempt to use `EXPLAIN` in the function body. The only way to do this (that I know of) is to use the `EXECUTE...` syntax with a query string. That doesn't have a delay - its also useless for the trigger.

Comment: You can set log_lock_waits, then it will log any lock waits longer than deadlock_timeout (default: one second).  If that doesn't show anything, you can log EXPLAIN plans with auto_explain, particularly using log_analyze, log_nested_statemets, and log_min_duration.

Comment: @jjanes That should be an answer.

Comment: @jjanes Thank you, that is exactly what I was thinking of / looking for and couldn't remember.